# JavaScript is not available. (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from a Twitter webpage using Python but instead of getting the data back, I keep getting "Javascript is not available". I've enabled Javascript in my browser(chrome) but nothing changes.

Here is the error -->

```
<h1>JavaScript is not available.</h1>
<p>We’ve detected that JavaScript is disabled in this browser. Please enable JavaScript or switch to a supported browser to continue using twitter.com. You can see a list of supported browsers in our Help Center.</p>
```

Here is the code -->

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://twitter.com/search?q=%23developer%20advocate&src=typed_query&f=user"
source_code = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")
content = soup.find("div")
print(content)
```

I've tried enabling Javascript in my browser(chrome), I expected to get the required data back instead the error "Javascript is not availble" persists.

Comment: A) You're likely violating Twitter ToS; pretty sure they want you to use their APIs vs scraping
B) I'm curious why you think changing something in your browser will change the behavior of your python script that doesn't use your browser
C) You likely could use selenium (which can use your browser to then get you the data you dump to BS4)

Comment: But, you're not using your web browser.

Comment: I've used Selenium to fetch the data and it was successful. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I will never advise scraping twitter by violating their policies, you should use an API instead! But for the Javascript part, just pass user agent in headers in your requests.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

url = "https://twitter.com/search?q=%23developer%20advocate&src=typed_query&f=user"
source_code = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")
content = soup.find("div")
print(content)
```